# How to find the expectation of a product with a random variable in the product bounds?

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the expectation of a product like this:

$$\prod_{i=0}^X f(i)$$

where X is a random variable. I am having a very hard time finding resources online. I only get results on the product of random variables.

Any help with regards finding this expectation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably, $X$ is a discrete random variable, taking values in $\mathbb{N}_0$. Do you know the distribution of $X$?

Answer (score 1):

The product $\prod\limits_{i=0}^X f(i)$ is only well-defined if the random variable takes values in $\mathbb{N}_0$, i.e.

$$X \sim \sum_{n \geq 0} p_n \cdot \delta_n$$

where $\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} p_n = 1$, $p_n = \mathbb{P}(X = n) \geq 0$. This means that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \prod_{i=0}^X f(i) \right) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \left(\prod_{i=0}^n f(i) \right) \cdot p_n$$

Whether this series converges, depends on the sequence $(p_n)_n$ and $f$.

For example, if $X$ has Binomial distribution, i.e.

$$X \sim \underbrace{(1-p)}_{p_0} \delta_0 + \underbrace{p}_{p_1} \delta_1$$

for some $p \in (0,1)$, we have

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \prod_{i=0}^X f(i) \right) = (1-p) \cdot f(0) + p \cdot f(0) \cdot f(1)$$

Comment: You probably also need some nice condition on $\mathbb{E}[X]$ like $\mathbb{E}[X]<\infty$ like in Wald's equation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald's_equation

Comment: @Alex Yes, that's why I asked flauntZeta whether the distribution of $X$ is given. I don't see why $\mathbb{E}X<\infty$ should imply that the series converges (for example if $p_n = n^{-3}$ and $f$ grows exponentially).